# How do I batch multiple columns of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two operations, the first is

```
df['A'] = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(df['aScore'],
                               loc=df['amean'],scale=df['astd'])*100
df['B'] = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(df['bScore'],
                               loc=df['bmean'],scale=df['bstd'])*100
df['C'] = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(df['cScore'],
                               loc=df['cmean'],scale=df['cstd'])*100
```

another one is

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['D'].transform(sum)
df['E'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['E'].transform(sum)
df['F'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['F'].transform(sum)
```

Is there any way to avoid repeating(as well as looping) and write them in one sentence?

Comment: not really for the first, for the second `df[['D', 'E', 'F']] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])[['D', 'E', 'F']].transform('sum')` should work

Answer (score 0):

For the first operation, you can use the apply() method with a lambda function to apply the same operation to multiple columns at once.

Define the function that applies the norm.cdf operation

```
def apply_norm_cdf(column_name, mean_column_name, std_column_name):
return scipy.stats.norm.cdf(df[column_name],
                            loc=df[mean_column_name],
                            scale=df[std_column_name]) * 100
```

Apply the norm.cdf operation to multiple columns at once

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df.apply(lambda row: apply_norm_cdf(row.name + 'Score', row.name + 'mean', row.name + 'std'), axis=1)
```

For the other one, same groupby() operation multiple times for each column can be simplified as below.

```
df[['D', 'E', 'F']] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])[['D', 'E', 'F']].transform(sum)
```